# HTML Table content insert and clear using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table and assigned a id to it. Initially there is no content.i.e., just the table tag.

I am using this to clear the table contents

```
function emptyTable ( tableRef )
{
    var resultCount = tableRef.rows.length;
    for ( var i=0; i<resultCount; i++)
    {
        if ( tableRef.rows[tableRef.rows.length-1].cells[0].tagName == "TD" )
        {
            tableRef.deleteRow(tableRef.rows.length-1);
        }
    }
}
```

tableRef will have the table id. For first time i have clear the table and the rows are inserted.

```
var resultListRef = document.getElementById("showReferencesDet");

var row = resultListRef.insertRow(0);
var newCell  = row.insertCell(0);
newCell.innerHTML = 'Select';
var newCell2  = row.insertCell(1);
newCell2.innerHTML = 'Reference Number';

var row = resultListRef.insertRow(resultListRef.rows.length);
var newCell  = row.insertCell(0);
name="referenceId" value="' + id + '" />';
newCell.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="referenceId" name="referenceId" value="' + allVars + '" />';

var newCell2  = row.insertCell(1);
newCell2.innerHTML = RefNo;
```

It works for the first time but didn't works in the 2nd time.

Please help to solve it.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Can you add a demo? Do you have any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: The error i got was "tableRef is null" in emptyTable ( tableRef ) function.

Answer (score 0):

just change your for loop

```
  function emptyTable ( tableRef )
    {
        document.getElementById(tableRef).innerHTML='';
    }
```

Comment: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: ensure table with given id is exist before calling this method.

Comment: For the first time it gives and append the data. But can't to do it in the next time.

Comment: What is this 

name="referenceId" value="' + id + '" />';

and



newCell2.innerHTML = RefNo;

Comment: Name of the check box which is to be inserted as a table cell and Ref No is to display in the second cell in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var row = resultListRef.insertRow(resultListRef.rows.length);
```

you can do:

```
var row = resultListRef.insertRow(-1);
```

and the row will be inserted as the last row.

Removing the rows of a table doesn't necessarily remove all content, it may still contain empty text nodes, thead and tfoot elements, etc. Consider:

```
function emptyTable ( tableRef ) {
  while (tableRef.firstChild) {
    tableRef.removeChild(tableRef.firstChild);
  }
}
```

That will clear *everything* from inside the table (but not properties and attributes of the table itself) as if you had `<table ... ></table>`.

However, you may want to keep header rows and footers. In that case, you just want to remove the tBody elements:

```
function emptyTableBodies ( tableRef ) {
  var tBodies = tableRef.tBodies;
  for (var i=tBodies.length; i;) {
    tableRef.removeChild(tBodies[--i]);
  }
}
```

so you can do:

```
<table id="t0">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>head
  </thead>
  <tr><td>0
  <tr><td>0
  <tr><td>0
  <tr><td>0
</table>

<button onclick="emptyTableBodies(document.getElementById('t0'))">Empty table bodies</button>
```

Note that a table with no content is not valid, so fix that as soon as you can after the above.